# Using game sub-tags but not using the game tag

Tags: discussion, tags, sub-tags, dwarf-fortress

This issue came up recently after I retagged a pair ([1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106280/how-to-track-down-a-night-creature-in-a-city), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11169/how-can-i-arm-a-friendly-peasant)) of questions to add the [dwarf-fortress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress) tag. Both of the questions only had the [dwarf-fortress-adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress-adventure) tag.

A while later the changes were reverted and a discussion began in the comments of the [first question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106280/how-to-track-down-a-night-creature-in-a-city). My feeling was that questions should have their game-related tag, even if there are relevant sub-tags which would imply it.

They believed that having the one tag removed the need for the other, as people could still look at questions from both tags by using wildcards in their search (e.g. dwarf-fortress*).

I feel that it's unreasonable to expect an arbitrary user, while browsing tags, for example, to assume that the tag for a game wouldn't include all the questions about that game. And other games with subtags can't be wildcarded as conveniently ([team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2) and [tf2-pyro](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-pyro)).

Additionally, for consistency, only 2 of 21 [dwarf-fortress-adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress-adventure) questions don't also have the [dwarf-fortress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress) tag.

So, in essence, do people feel that a question about a specific game should always have that tag, regardless of its other tags? Should those questions in particular have the dwarf-fortress tag added back?

Comment: I asked [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7036/revisiting-the-dwarf-fortress-tags) roughly a month ago.  We didn't have any resolution on it, so I'm not sure how to handle it.  The main question seems to be if the subtag is even needed, if the two modes of play are so similar.  I'd prefer to separate the two out, as there are several questions that ask specifically about Adventure Mode.

Comment: Even searching `dwarf fortress` autocorrects to `[dwarf-fortress]`, thereby excluding `[dwarf-fortress-adventure]` questions.  So I agree with you: if the tags aren't going to me merged, then all of the Adventure questions should also have the primary tag added so that people can properly find them when they want all questions about the game in any mode.

Comment: Related: [Do we need a separate tag for Dwarf Fortress adventure mode?](/q/1460/)

Comment: Interesting how in 2010 they were split (your link), and [in 2012](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4033) it was revisited with an answer suggesting what this question was about (games always having their games tag), and now it's come up again in 2013 due to the two not becoming fully consistent!

Comment: @Samthere You see why I punted on this issue. :)

Comment: Related: [Questions tagged \[minecraft\] and \[minecraft-redstone\]](/q/5545) • [Using both \[minecraft\] and \[minecraft-tekkit\] tags](/q/5688)

Comment: Once again a reason SE should implement the [implicit tagging hierarchy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58073/146482) - any [tag:df]-* tagged question would implicitly be considered tagged [tag:dwarf-fortress] without anyone tagging having to remember to add that tag...

Answer (score 7):

Having looked at the link in the comments from fbueckert, I'd like to propose the following solution:

- All Dwarf Fortress related questions receive the [dwarf-fortress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress) tag.
- All fortress mode questions receive the [df-fortress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/df-fortress) tag.
- All adventure mode questions receive the [df-adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/df-adventure) tag (replacing [dwarf-fortress-adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress-adventure)).
- If necessary, other tags can be used (e.g. [df-modding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/df-modding)).

This way, there is still a parent tag shared by all Dwarf Fortress questions, in honour of them all relating to the same game, but the distinction between questions that apply to only one game mode remains clear.

This also helps future-proof the tags - as adventure mode implements more fortress mode features, questions will increasingly apply to both modes, so the [dwarf-fortress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress) tag alone will host questions that could equally apply to either.

Shortening the child tags to *df-* keeps them concise.

Comment: I have to disagree with shortening the tags, that's going to make them less discoverable. Otherwise I'm good with this.

Comment: I like this solution much better than condensing them into a single tag. As I pointed out in the comments on [this question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7036/revisiting-the-dwarf-fortress-tags?lq=1), I think that would be harmful.